# Визуализация AI алгоритма не в консоли C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, разработка-игр, движок

Подскажите простой способ визуализировать определенную логику.

Для примера есть поле 50х50 квадратов (или гексагон) на нём есть определенные юниты, каждый занимает свою клетку. Потом они по моей логике будут взаимодействовать, а я хочу это увидеть.

Windows form не предлагайте, слишком узко.

Желательно 2d движок. Потому, что 3д это пока не нужно и сложно.

Comment: ну возьмите любой соответствующий движок, хотя бы unity3d, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: > я хочу это увидеть.
> Windows form не предлагайте, слишком узко.

Вы определитесь, шашечки или ехать? Возможностей WinForms для описанных задач вам точно хватит.

Comment: Очень сильно постараюсь сделать это дело на WPF. Надеюсь его возможностей хватит. Просто там в графическом плане всё плачевно. А так я думаю хватит пока-что.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если не читать ваш предущий вопрос, то чем плохо для визуализации результата работы алгоритма использовать WPF? Будет у вас Grid с N Columns и M rows - представление, логика в модели.

Понимаю, что вы хотите сразу сделать задел на будущее, но начинать, имхо, имеет смысл от простого к сложному. Зная, как это должно себя вести + изучив азы какого-нибудь 2D движка, повторить это будет быстро.

Comment: Спасибо, что даёте понятные ответы. Я думаю вы правы, я сильно разогнался)) Я сейчас попробую на WPF сделать, а потом перенесу куда-то.. Но всё же мне много не понятно в WPF в частности как там устроенно Grid и как адекватно всё это сделать, что бы эмулировать игровое поле. Я не к сожалению материалов по этой теме не нашёл.

Comment: @Kimel, можете посмотреть мой суперкод здесь

https://bitbucket.org/Veikedo/life.thegame/src

Реализация игры "жизнь". Как раз грид используется

http://f5.s.qip.ru/14Jj1hsY7.png

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но к сожалению у меня не билдится. Пишет вот что:
Error 3 Metadata file 'C:\Users\Kimel\Desktop\Veikedo-life.thegame-850c1d40fd4d\Life.Game\bin\Debug\Life.Logic.dll' could not be found C:\Users\Kimel\Desktop\Veikedo-life.thegame-850c1d40fd4d\Life.CLI\CSC Life.CLI

И так во всех проэктах. Какую-то Life.Logic.dll не находит. 

И вторая ошибка 
Error 1 'Life.Logic.GameStateCalculator' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()' C:\Users\Kimel\Desktop\Veikedo-life.thegame-850c1d40fd4d\Life.Game\GameStateCalculator.cs 7 18 Life.Logic

Comment: @Kimel, попробуйте

https://bitbucket.org/Veikedo/life.thegame/src/528477ce32bd8943f8a8ed0e865838d0db0cc66f/?at=sub